# Voltage Divider, \$V_{out} = IR_2\$

Tags: voltage

I understand the proof in the link below and how a voltage divider works. This question is about a definition in the proof:

$$V_{out} = I \times R_2$$

If \$I\$ is the current in the series circuit, then I understand that the current times the resistance of the second resistor (\$R_2\$) will be the voltage drop across \$R_2\$ (in a DC circuit).

Will \$V_{out}\$ always be equal to the voltage drop across \$R_2\$? Is this known as a result of experiment or the result of some other math? Or am I just thinking about this the wrong way?

[Voltage Divider article at WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider).

Answer (score 2):

As you have already said, the formula gives you the voltage drop across that resistor.  So it is the difference in voltage between one side of the resistor and the other.  As this resistor is the "bottom" half of the divider the voltage at the lowest end will always be 0V, because that is where it is connected to. It can never* be anything else.  So that means that the voltage at the other side of that resistor must equal to the voltage drop across the resistor - it can't be anything else.  And as that point is also \$V_{OUT}\$ then that's what your output voltage will always be.

---

*as long as you measure with respect to that point as ground

Answer (score 2):

> Will Vout always be equal to the voltage drop across R2?

In this particular context, the output voltage is identical to the voltage *across* \$R_2\$.

[image]

However, we could define another output voltage to be the voltage *across* \$R_1\$

$$V'_{out} = V_{R1} = V_{in}\frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2}$$

The point being that voltage division can be used to find the voltage across either resistor.  In other words, *regardless* of how one defines the output voltage, the following holds:

$$V_{R1} =  V_{in}\frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2}$$

$$V_{R2} =  V_{in}\frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2}$$

The above equations tell us that the voltage \$V_{in}\$ *divides* across the resistances *in proportion* to the total resistance.  *This* is voltage division.

Which resistor one chooses to take the output voltage across is irrelevant to the fundamental result.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, \$V_{out}\$ will always be equal to the voltage drop across \$R_2\$.

Imagine you measure \$V_{out}\$ using a voltmeter. Now measure the voltage drop across \$R_2\$. Did you change anything?

No. You need to place the test prods in the same two points.